definition of connected space
A space $X$ is connected if it cannot be written as the union of two or more disjoint open sets.
Implicitly here there is a finiteness condition, right?
As in, if I write down a partition of $X$ with infinitely many open sets, $X$ may still be connected?

The assertions:

$X$ can be written as the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets;
$X$ can be written as the union of a family $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ of disjoint non-empty open sets, with $\#\Lambda>1$.

are equivalent. It is trivial that $1.~\implies~2.$ And, if the second condition holds, you fix some $\eta\in\Lambda$, and then $X_\eta$ and $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{\eta\}}X_\lambda$ are two disjoint non-empty open sets whose union is $X$.

No, because you can turn any partition (finite or infinite) into a partition of $2$ sets - just take one of the sets in the partition, and the union of all the others. Remember, any union of open sets is open.
By the way, note that a space is connected if it can't be written as a disjoint union of two nonempty open sets. Because there is always the trivial partition $X=X\cup\emptyset$.
